# Sitefinity editor immediately closes itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sitefinity

I've added an angular module of my own creation to a widget I built.

When I click to edit this module, it immediately closes. No console errors or warnings, nothing to indicate why in the logs. It simply starts looking like it's loading (grayed background, loading bar) then immediately closes itself like nothing happened.

I modeled it very closely on [this multi-image select module](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/use-multiple-selector-with-image-field). The meat of my module `enhanced-image-field.js` file is:

```
(function ($) {
    var sfFields = angular.module('sfFields');
    sfFields.requires.push('EnhancedImageField'); //<- will break on this line in debugger as expected...
    angular.module('EnhancedImageField', ['sfServices', 'sfImageSelector'])
        .directive('EnhancedImageField', ['serverContext', 'sfMediaService', 'sfMediaFilter', function (serverContext, sfMediaService, sfMediaFilter) {
        //... but code inside here never gets called
    }]);
});
```

In my DesignerView.Simple.json file:

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "components": [
    "sf-image-field",
    "sf-expander",
    "sf-style-dropdown"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "client-components/fields/enhanced-image-field/enhanced-image-field.js"
  ]
}
```

If I remove the `sfFields.requires.push('EnhancedImageField');` line, the editor stays open, albeit void of any fields or functionality encapsulated here.

My `designerview-simple.js` file makes it through all of the `requires` calls, but it never calls any of the inner code:

```
(function ($) {
     var simpleViewModule = angular.module('simpleViewModule', ['expander', 'designer', 'ngSanitize']);
     angular.module('designer').requires.push('simpleViewModule');
     angular.module('designer').requires.push('sfFields');
     angular.module('designer').requires.push('sfSelectors');
     angular.module('designer').requires.push('ngSanitize');

     simpleViewModule.controller('SimpleCtrl', ['$scope', 'propertyService', function ($scope, propertyService) {
        $scope.feedback.showLoadingIndicator = true;

        propertyService.get()
        .then(
            function (data) {
                //... Code here never gets called!
            }
        )
    }]);
});
```

I'm not overly familiar with angularjs but nothing here jumps out at me.

Answer (score 0):

```
̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶$̶)̶ ̶{̶
    var sfFields = angular.module('sfFields');
    sfFields.requires.push('EnhancedImageField');
    angular.module('EnhancedImageField', ['sfServices', 'sfImageSelector'])
        .directive('EnhancedImageField', ['serverContext', 'sfMediaService', 'sfMediaFilter', function (serverContext, sfMediaService, sfMediaFilter) {
        //... a bunch of code that never gets called
    }]);
̶}̶)̶;̶
```

Comment: No change in behavior. The wrapping function also exists in the code of every other angular module included in Sitefinity.

Comment: Looks like this is a "Russian Doll" problem. Fix one problem, lift the doll, and another problem reveals itself.

Answer (score 0):

`EnhancedImageField` should be `enhancedImageField`, apparently camel-casing is super-important.